Number of homomorphisms from $\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\Z\oplus \Z$ to $S_3$
I read that a homomorphism is fully determined by where its generators are mapped to.
Let $f\colon\, \Z\oplus \Z\to S_3$ be a group homomorphism.
Generators of $\Z\oplus \Z$ are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. I can map $(1,0)$ to any permutation I want. I just need to make sure that $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ commute.
Suppose:

$f(1,0) = id$ (6 options for $f(0,1)$)

$f(1,0) = (12), (23) \text{ or } (13)$ (2 options each for $f(0,1)$)

$f(1,0) = (123) \text{ or } (132)$ (3 options each for $f(0,1)$)


Thus, total of $6 + 2×3 + 3×2 = 18$ homomorphisms.
Note: I counted the options by using the fact that the size of centralizer of an element is equal to order of the group divided by size of conjugacy class of the element.
It looks like, this can be generalized. From $\Z\oplus \Z$ to $S_n$, there are $n!\times k$ homomorphisms where $k$ is the number of disjoint conjugacy classes in $S_n$.
Is my conjecture true? I raise this doubt because I assumed that each pair of commuting permutations $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ determines a homomorphism. I don't know for certain if this is true.

@Randall this is not a constraint. All elements of $S_6$ satisfy what you write.

Did you mean $(n!)k$ rather than $nk$? Otherwise, in your example, that would say that there are $9$ homomorphisms rather than $18$.

@GeoffreyTrang yes, fixed.

Yes, now can you find the formula for a general finite group?

@SteveD I don't see how.

It is answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271752/number-of-commuting-pairs-triples-n-tuples-in-gl-nf-q-and-other-groups#:~:text=The%20number%20of%20commuting%20pairs%20in%20any%20finite%20group%20G,of%20conjugacy%20classes%20of%20G.

In particular, your conjecture holds.

To address your comments about commuting pairs being enough: your domain is a free Abelian group on 2 generators, and that means that any map from it to another Abelian group is uniquely determined by where those two generators are sent. Now just note that if $x,y\in G$ commute, then they generate an Abelian subgroup.

Did you understand the solution?

@MoisheKohan I aplogise. I have no intention to ghost you. I studied group theory for one semester only. I don't know orbit stabilizer theorem yet. I have college exams going on.  I'll get back to learning that and scrutinizing your answer when I'm free. Though I have upvoted, I'll accept the answer only after I understand it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem

For every group $G$ there is a bijection between $Hom(\mathbb Z^2, G)$ and the set $C_2(G)$ of ordered pairs of commuting elements of $G$. The bijection $\beta$ is given by
$$
\beta: \phi\mapsto (\phi(a), \phi(b)),
$$
where $a, b$ are fixed generators of $\mathbb Z^2$ and $\phi: \mathbb Z^2\to G$ is a homomorphism. Thus, you are asking about the  cardinality $c$ of $C_2(G)$ for finite groups $G$.
We have
$$
c= \sum_{h\in G} |Z_G(h)|
$$
where $Z_G(h)$ is the centralizer of $h$ in $G$. The group $G$ acts on the conjugacy class $C_h\subset G$ (of $h\in G$)
by conjugation; the action is transitive  with the stabilizer of every element equal $Z_G(h)$. Thus, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, we have
$$
 |G|= |C_h|\cdot |Z_G(h)|
 $$
for every $h\in G$. Thus,
$$
c= \sum_{h\in G} |Z_G(h)|= \sum_{h\in G} \frac{|G|}{|C_h|}= |G|  \sum_{h\in G} \frac{1}{|C_h|}. 
$$
In order to compute $\sum_{h\in G} \frac{1}{|C_h|}$ we pick a representative $h_i$ from every conjugacy class in $G$, $i=1,...,N$, where $N$ is the number of conjugacy classes in $G$. Then
$$
 \sum_{h\in G} \frac{1}{|C_h|}= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{g\in C_{h_i}} \frac{1}{|C_{h_i}|}.
$$
The number of summands in each $\sum_{g\in C_{h_i}} \frac{1}{|C_{h_i}|}$ is $|C_{h_i}|$, hence,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{g\in C_{h_i}} \frac{1}{|C_{h_i}|}= \sum_{i=1}^N  1= N. 
$$
Putting it all together, we obtain,
$$
|Hom(\mathbb Z^2, G)|= c=   |G|  \sum_{h\in G} \frac{1}{|C_h|} = |G|\cdot N,
$$
where $N$ is the number of conjugacy classes in $G$, confirming your conjecture. For information about computation of the number $N$ for various finite groups, see answers to this  Mathoverflow question.

I am sorry for this late response, I was busy with semester exams. I see that $|G|= |C_h|\cdot |Z_G(h)|$ is more easier understand through the lens of group actions... For those who don't know group action: See my answer.
